# How to register a custom view engine in magellan?

Tags: wpf, winforms, magellan

I'm all new to magellan, and as an attempt to learn it, I've built a custom view engine for supporting windows forms as specified in the documentation at codeplex.
But how to register this new ViewEngine? There it is given,

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new FormsViewEngine(new DefaultViewActivator()));
```

But what I can see is that, `ViewEngines` is not a Static Class and moreover it does not have a `Engines` Property. I know I'm missing something, but what is it?

So, How to register my `ViewEngine` to Magellan? Where and When should I register it?

PS: I'm using the latest update of magellan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the view engines are now configured on the `ControllerRouteCatalog`.

One of the goals in Magellan 2.0 was to reduce the number of static locators.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like things have changed a bit. A few search for references of `ViewEngine` Class in the Magellan source gave the answer.

Now `ViewEngines` just provide default collection and no more handles ViewEngine registrations. I managed to create my own `ViewEngineCollection` and pass it to the contructor of `ControllerRouteCatalog`.

My bad, I should have done that before. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I also just answered your question on this page: http://code.google.com/p/magellan-framework/wiki/WinForms

Comment: Thank you. I was a bit confused with the documentation at your blog and codeplex. It will be better if you can update them or indicate that its outdated.